# Why is no error thrown for infinite loops

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code snippet

```
const loopFn = function(num) {

  for(let a = 0; a < num || 10; a++) { 
    console.log(a)
  }

}

let b = loopFn(8)

console.log(b)
```

I know the correct way to write is `a < (num || 10)`, I'm just curious why it causes an infinite loop instead of reporting an error.

Comment: Because 10 is always true and this is legit syntax

Comment: Because `a < num || 10` means : `if(a < 10) or if(10)`. And since 10 is truthy, the condition is always true.

Answer (score 1):

What you mean do to is

```
const count = num || 10;

for(let a = 0; a < count; a++) { 
    console.log(a)
}
```

But what you're actually doing is saying while `a` is less than `8` OR `10` is `true`

Answer (score 1):

The language/execution engine does not report it as an error because there is no inherent issue with infinite loops itself.

Depending upon the use-case infinite loops are of help. For instance, in daemon scripts that are meant to process jobs from a queue.

Answer (score 0):

The condition of your for loop is:

```
a < num || 10
```

If either a < num is true, or 10 is true the loop continues.

Try in your browser console, and you will see, that 10 is always true.
if(10)
alert("true")

If you want the loop to end if a is not < 10, try this:

```
for(let a = 0; a < num || a < 10; a++)
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of having a second check. You should use an OR operator instead of an AND operator.

Comment: `a < num || a < 10` is not equals to `a < (num || 10)`. Consider `num = 8`.

Answer (score 0):

The second part of for loop is condition; and boolean result of that condition tells the for loop to stop or continue; when you put `10` it will be evaluated as true; hence for loop never end; as if you writing

```
if (10) {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not wrapping the logic inside brackets, then it will divide like this

either it will check `a<num` is true or `10` is a true expression.

It taking 10 as a true expression because its a non zero number. So every time the loop getting the second expression as true and so on.

If you wrap the condition then it will check like this

either `a<num` or `a<10`

It will stop when it match any of the expression false.

It just the use of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because of the Operator Precedence in JavaScript (or any language).
When you pass the expression `a<num||10` to your for loop's break condition, it evaluates the `a<num` part first, and then the `||10` part.
`a<num` will provide you with a true/false value  and `10` will give you 10 (a truthy value), hence `a<num||10` will essentially check if one of `a<num` or `10` is a  truthy value, which is true. Therefore, the infinite loop.
More on Operator Precedence:
[MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)